# Getting all sub-sites using rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have tried the below code for getting all sub-sites using rest...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetriveSites,"sp.js");

function RetriveSites()
{
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&@target=",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
alert("sds");
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}



</script>
```

I am not able to get sub-sites ,it is just showing an alert with some random data. Please help me with the code.

Comment: The alert with random data is actually error log I assume, as you have an alert in your error callback. Please post the error details

Comment: yes it is going to the error. I think the problem is with the url I have given,

Comment: Also the SP.AppContextSite(@target) is used for cross domain calls. Where are you calling this javascript from? Are you trying to get subsites in another domain?

Comment: no, in the same domain, please help me with the url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs` only when you are making any cross domain calls like for eg: inside a SharePoint hosted app or Provider hosted app etc. To get the sub sites under the current site use below format for url.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/webs",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: function (data) {
           console.log(data.d.results);
    },
  error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: Its working now, now I need to display all sub site names on a site. data.d.result shows only "object object"

Comment: That's because it is an object. To view it in the console use `console.log("%O", data.d.results);`

Answer (score 0):

`http://<site url>/_api/web/webs`

This call is not enough, unless if all users are allowed to access a subsite. It will throw a `System.UnathorizedAcces` exception if a subsite is not available for access to a certain user.